# Problemas ao conectar MongoDB usando IntelliJ

Tags: java, mongodb, intellij-idea, intellij

Estou fazendo um projeto de jogo em Java usando o IntelliJ IDEA, optei por usar o IntelliJ porque algumas funções não estavam funcionando no Maven. Porém preciso conectar o MongoDB ao projeto mas estou tendo problemas na hora de importar as bibliotecas mongo, que acabam não sendo reconhecidas pelo programa. Já adicionei um driver do mongo com java e o problema continua. Já fiz projetos anteriormente no Maven com o mongo e eles funcionavam normalmente após eu adicionar as dependências no pom.xml, mas como o IntelliJ não possui pom eu não sei o que fazer. Alguma solução?

Answer (score -2):

No intelliJ:

1- Na aba de database você clica no "+", seleciona "Datasource" e escolhe "mongoDB".

2- no "host" e "Port" devem ser o mesmo do seu banco de dados do MongoDB. (se tiver user e senha, tem os campos de autentificação para você preencher).

3-Na mesma janela, tem um botão de teste de conexão, caso faltar driver, é só clicar no "Download" que ele fará para ti.

4-Depois clica em "test conection" que se preenchido corretamente e o banco aberto, ele apresentará sucesso e poderá clicar em "OK".

Ele carregará para ti na janela do Database.

Comment: Essa parte eu já tinha chegado a fazer antes de relatar o problema aqui, e conectou tudo certinho, tanto que eu até conseguia ver meus dados salvos no IntelliJ. O problema está na hora de programar a interação com o BD, pois o programa não reconhece as bibliotecas do Mongo. Por não ser um arquivo Maven, não há um pom onde eu possa adicionar as dependências também.